# How to align left for a text outside a table with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to align the text **"Filter By:"** lefts the table. For the margin, it may not work when the windows screen has been resized (responsive). I tried the `text-align: left` or `center` but it didn't work as my expected.

Actually, the `div` element can be changed to another one to make it work.

Here is the **Fiddle** link:
https://jsfiddle.net/a26jsLg5/

See the following screen-shot of how it should look like:

[image]

```css
.searchType table {
        border: 1px solid #A6A6A6;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
```

```html
<TD style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: text-top">
  <DIV>Filter by:</DIV>
  <DIV class=searchType>
    <TABLE>
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>
            <INPUT type=radio CHECKED value=FullMap />
            <LABEL>Com 1</LABEL>
          </TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT type=radio value=MissingCourses />
            <LABEL>Com 2</LABEL>
          </TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT type=radio value=NeedToLearn />
            <LABEL>Com 3</LABEL>
          </TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this .https://codepen.io/jayakrishnancn/pen/WjBpZa

1st method with javascript

change this line

```
<DIV>Filter by:</DIV>
<DIV class=searchType>
```

to

```
<DIV class="searchType">
<DIV id="filter_text" style="margin:0 auto">Filter by:</DIV>
```

and add this script to page

```
<script>
 $('#filter_text').width($('#filter_text').next().width()); 
</script>
```

2nd id u know the maximum width of table in advance then use this

```
<DIV class='searchType' style="width: 200px;margin:0  auto">
<DIV>Filter by:</DIV>
<TABLE style="width:100%">
```

here no script is needed, also "filter by" will stay in the right place (in previous method "filter by" will be placed in left and move to right only when jquery funtion run.

Comment: That works very well with the first solution. I'm trying the second one but it didn't work when the windows resized. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: i have made changes . take look at it.

Comment: about @Bhuwan Bhatt s answer, your code will always align both table and 'filterLabel' div to left by default. it wont appear in middle (when resize above width of table ) as he was trying to do.

Comment: @David Gilbertson has a better way to do it . but in question you said that you want to "align text outside a table with CSS".  otherwise its a better way.

Comment: Actually, I would like to make the div with `Filter by:` work but not to change anything from the `margin: 0 auto` of the table

Comment: In my view, the Bhuwan Bhatt's comment was also a great idea and I would send him a vote because I didn't mention the `table` element has been generated from server code, couldn't add the `caption` element insides.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a small correction in your css. Remove `margin: 0 auto` form your `.searchType table` css

```css
.searchType table {
        border: 1px solid #A6A6A6;
    }
```

```html
<TD style="VERTICAL-ALIGN: text-top">
  <DIV class="filterLabel">Filter by:</DIV>
  <DIV class=searchType>
    <TABLE>
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD>
            <INPUT type=radio CHECKED value=FullMap />
            <LABEL>Com 1</LABEL>
          </TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT type=radio value=MissingCourses />
            <LABEL>Com 2</LABEL>
          </TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT type=radio value=NeedToLearn />
            <LABEL>Com 3</LABEL>
          </TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the `<caption>` element for this. It goes inside your table element, you can then align it left.

```css
.searchType table {
  border: 1px solid #A6A6A6;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

table caption {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<DIV class=searchType>
  <TABLE>
    <CAPTION>Filter by:</CAPTION>
    <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <INPUT type=radio CHECKED value=FullMap />
          <LABEL>Full learning map</LABEL>
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT type=radio value=MissingCourses />
          <LABEL>Missed courses</LABEL>
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT type=radio value=NeedToLearn />
          <LABEL>Courses need to learn</LABEL>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
</DIV>
```

More about the caption element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption